# Universal hash function when size of hash is p^m

Tags: uniform-distribution, hash-function

Can we define universal hash function from $U \rightarrow T$ when $T=\{0,1,2,..,m-1\}$ and $m=p^a$? (where $p$ is a prime and a is an integer)

I know that we can define universal hash funciton when $m=p$ and p is a prime in this way:

$h_{\alpha}(x)=\alpha \cdot x \space mod \space m$ but what about $m=p^a$?

a hash function is universal if $Prob(h(x)=i)=1/m \space$ for $i=0,1,...m-1$.

Comment: You can define $h_a(x)=ax\pmod m$ for any $m$ and $a$, as long as $a$ is relatively prime with $m$.

Comment: Why did you change from uniform hash in your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076711/number-of-uniform-hash-functions) to universal hash here?  They appear the same.

Comment: yes,they are same.